# Can I flash magisk on encrypted HTC10?

Tags: magisk, htc-10

Phone in question is european HTC 10 with Oreo.

Here is what I did:

- Unlocked the bootloader following procedure from htcdev.
- Flashed TWRP.
- Sideloaded SuperSu.

Then I figured that I don't want SuperSu because of SafetyNet. (fails both basicIntegrity and ctsProfile)

- I didn't changed anything on system partition manually.
- Did full unroot in SuperSu.

Now basicIntegrity passes, but ctsProfile fails. I think its because
   bootloader is unlocked.

- Now I want to flash Magisk, but TWRP can't mount data partition because disk is encrypted(password doesn't work). This makes me unsure if it is possible to flash magisk.
- Can I ADB sideload Magisk? or flash it with fastboot?

Ideally I want to end up with rooted phone that passes both cts and basicIntegrity.

Comment: Question - do you know your PIN/password to enter the OS normally?  If so, make sure sure you have the option set in Android Settings (probably somewhere in Security) to ask for your PIN/password on startup.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it doesn't matter data is encrypted(click cancel on password prompt), I just put zips on microSD and flashed them via TWRP (install option), everything passed.

Safety net passes completely and root works.